# How to get the names of the windows that are open and switch to a target window?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have been searching everywhere on how to do this specifically but to no avail.

Let's say I want to get a list of all the open windows/apps on my device:
[image: Open apps]

The next thing I want to do is to search for a window with a name "Notepad", or maybe "Facebook", then switch and maximize those window as the main window on the screen.

I've been using `pyautogui` module for switching tabs by automatically pressing `alt + tab` keys with the module. However, I believe it'll be prone to mistakes if I have no way of checking which tab/window is currently selected or maximized.

I was thinking of a solution that I can just continuously automate pressing `alt + tab` until the target window  name is in the current active window, but I don't know how to get the name of the current active window as well.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that `pyautogui` has a method to get the active window title as well.

```
import pyautogui
import time

target_window = 'notepad'
count = 0

while True:
    window_title = pyautogui.getActiveWindowTitle()

    if target_window not in window_title:
        count += 1
        with pyautogui.hold('alt'):
            for _ in range(0, count):
                 pyautogui.press('tab')

     time.sleep(0.25)
```